# Trouble installing Popcorn-time.to

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install popcorn-time.to [through their website](http://popcorn-time.to/).

After extracting it I tried to run ./Popcorn-Time but it gave me an error about missing libudev.so.0

I then proceeded to follow [this thread's advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576516/install-from-tar-gz).

It started running but now every time I open it, it isn't popcorn-time.to it is time4popcorn which looks a lot like malware.

[image: time4popcorn.eu]

I've had this happen to me before when I first started using Linux with Mint but now I'm not being able to fix it as easily.

This seems to be a common issue and I'm note even being able to install it through a ppa so I'm keeping and updating this thread for future people with this problem.

Comment: How did you install it? The one from "sh"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by going to [popcorn-time's reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PopCornTime/) and checking the sidebar for the official version: [popcorntime.sh](https://www.popcorntime.sh).

Downloaded it, ran it and it worked first try.

Answer (score 0):

Installing stuff from random websites registered in Tonga (.to) almost never comes to an happy end. 
Would you drop random pills some stranger gives you for free in a dark back alley just on his promise that it'll be fun? 
Of course you are not able to install it through a ppa. You wouldn't get the rainbow mystery pills in a pharmacy either. lol

Comment: What's wrong with Tonga websites though? Explanation link?

Comment: Anyway, how do I reverse this command? 
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so 
I'm not too sure about what it does. I know ln makes links between files though

Comment: The only reason to register a website in Tonga is to avoid legal persecution. So operations specializing in piracy and scamware register their sites in Tonga or eg. the Coconut Islands (.cc). I just wonder why you would install one of the safest OSs and then deliberately try to install ad-, spy- or malware?! 
And you DO realize, that pocorn-time basically is a torrent client? 
Meaning that while you stream your favourite pirated movie or series you also upload in the background and by that become fair game for legal firms specialized in making you pay for it. But go ahead and have fun.

Comment: Yeah I don't have to worry about that at all, I live in portugal, there has been no history of arrests/charges here, and yes I do realize that.

Comment: Thanks for warning me though :)